# React-admin: Unable to include credtials in dataProvider with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-admin

I'm trying to configure `dataProvider` to include credentials/cookies, and following [official repo's guide on sending Credentials To The API](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Authentication.md#sending-credentials-to-the-api) and [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54718199/cookie-based-authentication-via-rest-api-in-react-admin/54727456#54727456), I managed to produce a typescript version of it:

```
import * as ra_core from "ra-core";
import { fetchUtils } from "react-admin";
import simpleRestProvider from "ra-data-json-server";

const httpClient = (url: any, options?: ra_core.Options) => {
  if (options) { // Have to do a null check
    console.log("run options"); // It doesn't run from here
    options.credentials = "include";
  }

  console.log("run httpClient"); // It only runs here
  return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
};

const dataProvider= simpleRestProvider("http://localhost:3000", httpClient);

return <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>...</Admin>
```

Above code doesn't send cookies to server, as the `httpClient` takes an optional `options`, and performing null check skips it entirely. Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

Need to define `options` as empty object { }, and cast to `ra_core.Options`:

```
const httpClient = (url: any, options = {} as ra_core.Options) => { // <- here
  options.credentials = "include"; // typescript is happy now :)
  return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
};
```